# UI code works but change to XIB failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

the code below works

```
@interface MyUICollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {


}
@implementation UICollectionViewCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {


        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {

            _moreView = [[UIView alloc] init];
            _moreView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            _moreView.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - 70, 0, 45, 37);
            [self addSubview:_moreView];
            _moreView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapMoreView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToDoSomething)];
            [_moreView addGestureRecognizer:tapMoreView];



        }
        return self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)doSomeThing
{ 

}
```

when I touch the subview (gray block), it will trigger the event,
but I change to XIB(the sub view links to IBOutlet mUIView), and change the code as below,  goToDoSomething cannot be triggered.

Your comment welcome

[image]

```
@interface MyUICollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    IBOutlet UIView *mUIView;
}
@implementation UICollectionViewCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {


            NSArray *nibView =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyUICollectionViewCell"owner:self options:nil];
            UIView *bw = [nibView objectAtIndex:0] ;


            bw.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            [self.contentView addSubview:bw];
            mUIView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapMoreView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToDoSomething)];
            [mUIView addGestureRecognizer:tapMoreView];

        }
        return self;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)doSomeThing
{ 

}
```

Comment: Can you post your toDoSomething function declaration ?

Comment: Why are you using `NSArray *nibView =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IndexCreamCell"owner:self options:nil];
            UIView *bw = [nibView objectAtIndex:0] ;` where you can directly access the view in the same class. define a property, connect Outlets and use it directly.

Comment: @Dipen Panchasara  it is for load xib file for class MyUICollectionViewCell

Comment: MyUICollectionViewCell.xib

Comment: @arachide previously it was different, after edit it changed by you. and by the way you can't add view from cell to your view directly. use `UICollectionViewCell` wisely.

Comment: @Dipen Panchasara I do not understand, today I use UIScroll view on UICollectionViewCell has same result, using code the UITapGestureRecognizer/touch/scroll works, it can not trigger anything when using XIB mode

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer/touch/scroll works, it can not trigger anything when using XIB mode,  I have cared userInteraction/delegate/IBOutlet connection almost everything same, but on xib always has problem with UICollectionViewCell